Update Apache Superset User - password changed
I am using Superset extended API for User management and I want to edit user by
PUT /api/v1/security/users/{pk}

is most probably changing password as the login doesn't work anymore.
After some research I found, that issue is already opened on github
https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/29339
and also recognized as issue of FAB library
https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/pull/2179
It seems to me a bit inactive so I am looking for any workaround or any other direction.
